# focus на input при условии что он в середине экрана

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Я хочу сделать чтобы `input`'у вешался фокус когда он доскроливается до центра. Или при нажатии <kbd>Enter</kbd> ( Это я уже реализовал в скрипте ), если человек скроллит обратно, `input`'у вешается `focus` опять.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".interview__item input");
inputs.forEach(function(input, i) {
    //Следим за нажатием кнопки
    input.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
        var key = e.key;

        //Если нажат Enter
        if (key === 'Enter') {
            //<input disabled .... />
            input.disabled = true;

            if(i < inputs.length - 1)
            //Переводим фокус на следующее поле
                inputs[i + 1].focus();

            input.disabled = false;

        }
    });
});
```

```css
.interview__item{
  margin-top: 300px;
}

.interview__item:first-child{
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="maincontent__text">Вопрос <span class="maincontent__number"></span> из 4</p>


<div class="interview__input-wrapper">
  <div class="interview__item">
    <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Ваше имя?</div>
    <input type="text" class="interview__input change__input" placeholder="Моё имя.." autofocus />
  </div>
  <div class="interview__item">
    <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Сколько Вам?</div>
    <input type="text" class="interview__input change__input" placeholder="Мой возраст.." />
  </div>
  <div class="interview__item">
    <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Какой стаж?</div>
    <input type="text" class="interview__input change__input" placeholder="Мой стаж.." />
  </div>
  <div class="interview__item">
    <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">
      Сильные стороны?
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="interview__input change__input" placeholder="Мои сильные стороны.." />
  </div>
</div>
```

Буду очень признателен если поможете. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Это только для затравки.**

Потому как непонятно - какой элемент надо выделять если их несколько и т.д. и т.п.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".interview__item input");
inputs.forEach(function(input, i) {
    //Следим за нажатием кнопки
    input.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
        var key = e.key;

        //Если нажат Enter
        if (key === 'Enter') {
            //<input disabled .... />
            input.disabled = true;

            if(i < inputs.length - 1)
            //Переводим фокус на следующее поле
                inputs[i + 1].focus();

            input.disabled = false;

        }
    });
});

// +++ Добавлено +++
var timerID = null;
window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function () {
    clearTimeout( timerID );
    timerID = setTimeout( scroll, 100 );
} );

function scroll () {
    var gbr, p, ci, cp;
    inputs.forEach( function ( i ) {
        gbr = i.getBoundingClientRect();
        p = Math.abs( window.innerHeight / ( gbr.top + gbr.height / 2 ) - 2 );
        if ( gbr.top > 0 && gbr.bottom < window.innerHeight && ( !ci || p < cp ) ) {
            ci = i;
            cp = p;
        }
    } );
    if ( ci ) {
        ci.focus();
    }
}
```

```css
.interview__item{
  margin-top: 300px;
}

.interview__item:first-child{
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="maincontent__text">Вопрос <span class="maincontent__number"></span> из 4</p>


<div class="interview__input-wrapper">
  <div class="interview__item">
    <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Ваше имя?</div>
    <input type="text" class="interview__input change__input" placeholder="Моё имя.." autofocus />
  </div>
  <div class="interview__item">
    <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Сколько Вам?</div>
    <input type="text" class="interview__input change__input" placeholder="Мой возраст.." />
  </div>
  <div class="interview__item">
    <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">Какой стаж?</div>
    <input type="text" class="interview__input change__input" placeholder="Мой стаж.." />
  </div>
  <div class="interview__item">
    <div class="interview__item-text interview__text-main">
      Сильные стороны?
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="interview__input change__input" placeholder="Мои сильные стороны.." />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Огонь! Спасибо!!!